# Why the size of my game increased on deploying it to Android using Unity3D?

Tags: unity, android

When I deployed the game to '**Web Player**', it's size was just **2.4 MB** but when I deployed it to '**Android**', it's size got increased to **38 MB**.

Why this happened?  I can't provide any more information or code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web player uses a browser plugin to do its work. That means there is X amount of functionality that is already downloaded by the user before they ever download your game (tens of megabytes).  On android, the game is a standalone application so has to include all the functionality needed inside of itself.

Comment: So that increases the size by almost 14%? What's the solution for this?

Comment: Much more than 14%, but yeah.

Comment: Please provide the solution too. Like how I can reduce it's size?

Comment: Less coder, smaller assets. Not much besides that